# How to open music folder and not photo folder on iphone with jQuery plupload library

Tags: jquery, plupload

I am using plUpload jquery library to allow visitors to upload images and music to my website. I am initialising plupload with the following code:

```
  $plupload_init = array(
    'runtimes'            => "html5,flash,silverlight,html4",
    'browse_button'       => "BrowseButton",
    'container'           => "UploadContainer",
    'drop_element'        => "DragDropID",
    'file_data_name'      => "file-upload",            
    'multiple_queues'     => true,
    'max_file_size'       => $maxUploadSize.'b',
    'url'                 => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'flash_swf_url'       => includes_url('js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf'),
    'silverlight_xap_url' => includes_url('js/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap'),
    'filters'             => array(array('title' => __('Allowed Files'), 'extensions' => "jpg,gif,png,bmp,jpeg,mp3")),
    'multipart'           => true,
    'urlstream_upload'    => true,
    'chunk_size'        =>  '409600b',
    'max_retries' => 3,

    // additional post data to send to our ajax hook
    'multipart_params'    => $new_multipart_params,
  );

  $this->plupload_init = apply_filters('plupload_init', $plupload_init);
```

The code works brilliantly on the PC and also on the iPhone for images. However, the Upload button on the iPhone defaults to the camera roll and I want to be able to upload music from the iPhone.

Does anyone know a way of getting the iPhone to open the music folder when the upload button is clicked?

(As I write this I'm wondering if this is even possible as I've managed to find nothing about it on Google but thought I'd ask the experts just in case).

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The music on the iPhone is mostly coming from the iTunes Store and is thus paid content. It makes no sense for Apple to create a possibility to share that content. All files are personalized too.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as I added the question. It does make sense that they wouldn't allow it. I'll have to leave that functionality then. Thank you for your help. :-)